# How to Access Local Temp Table in SQL Server which is created in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I am creating a Temp Table (#Temp)in SSIS 2008 Package. I want to get access the data from this temp table in sql stored procedure. But i am getting the error invalid object in sql server when i am running the stored procedure.

I tried changing the delay validation as true and retain same connection as true
but no result.

Please correct on this.

Comment: This is the very first result when I googled it: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/

Comment: There is even a YouTube video if you don't like readinghttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaL7fbUou7E

Comment: I think @Sasi is asking how to access the global temp table outside of the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you are receiving is due to the global temp table not having an active connection after the SSIS package is finished.

See more here: [Why does a global temp table created by an SSIS package disappear after completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032729/why-does-a-global-temp-table-created-by-an-ssis-package-disappear-after-completi)

If this is for development or testing, you can create the global temp table locally, run your SSIS package after disabling your task that creates the global temp table, and now query that temp table after the SSIS package is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are using local temp table(#temp).
THe local temp table can se accessed across same session only.
So, there is no way you can access a local temp table created in SSIS through SSMS.

If you want to access the table created by SSIS through SSMS use a global temp table (##temp).
But calling the proc from sql will not make sense.
Try using execute SQL task to execute procedure from within SSIS package.
Send your SSIS package design to discuss further if it doesn't solve the issue.